# CakePHP, number of views

Tags: database, cakephp

Suppose, this is a db table in my project :

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>id</th>
     <th>title</th>
     <th>description</th>
     <th>created</th>
     <th>modified</th>
     <th>........</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Some Title</td>
     <td>Some Description</td>
     <td>7/8/2013 8:50</td>
     <td>7/8/2013 8:50</td>
     <td>........</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want to get the number how many times record 1 (id=1) has been seen. And that is in CakePHP. Is there any easy way to get this information ? I know `created` and `modified` are 2 fields whose values are automatically generated by CakePHP. So, is there any `field` or something that can be used here ? I marked this as `.........` . Or, is there any other way to do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but it's not hard to make yourself. (The hard part is to not increment the counter when search engine bots access the page if it's reachable to them.)

In the database create a field `viewcount INT DEFAULT 0` for example. In the controller, assuming the model is called `Model` and action is `view` (replace with actual names), add the code that increments the counter when the page is viewed:

```
function view( $id ) {
   // ....
   $this->Model->updateAll( 
       array( 'Model.viewcount', 'Model.viewcount + 1' ),
       array( 'Model.id', $id )
   );
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's cool, but, according to you, how do I stop search engines increment this value ?@Juhana

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP doesn't have an "automatic" viewed field. If you'd like this functionality you have to implement it yourself with the [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) method:

```
$this->Model->updateAll( 
    array('Model.views', 'Model.views + 1'),
    array('Model.id', $id)
);
```